# PHP Allowed memory size exhausted but tried to allocate is even fewer

Tags: php, memory, upload, out-of-memory, image-upload

I'm getting this error with a `imagecreatefrompng($image)` function:

```
Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 61440 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/SNIPED/httpdocs/app/helper.php on line 115\nPHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 147456 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/SNIPED/httpdocs/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 412
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure because **61440 bytes are fewer** than the **allowed 1073741824 bytes**. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of bytes PHP tried to allocate is incremental: it asked for 61440 bytes which, when added to the memory it was already using, is over the allowed amount of memory.